# Conditional Entropy on a quantized random variable

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Let $X$ and $Y$ be discrete random variables. The conditional entropy of $Y$ is:

$$H(Y|X) = \sum_{x}P(x)H(Y|X=x)$$

Assume we quantize $X$ with a quantizer $Q(X)$. How could we prove the resulting conditional entropy is greater than the original conditional entropy?

$$H(Y|X) \leq H(Y|Q(X))$$

Comment: Note that $Q(X)$ is conditionally independent of $Y$ given $X$. I.e., the Markov chain $Y-X-Q(X)$ holds. Now just use the DPI and expand mutual information in terms of entropy.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks, I just wonder what is the direction of this Markov chain and why?

Comment: To me, it has no meaningful notion of direction (this is why I wrote $Y-X$ and not $Y\rightarrow X$). I'm just using  'Markov chain' as a convenient way of describing some conditional independences, and these work in whatever direction you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here I just want to elaborate on what @stochasticboy321 commented. We know that $Q(X)$ is conditionally independent of $Y$ given $X$. So we have a Markov chain like this:

$$Y ----- X ----- Q(X)$$

Now, we are able to use The Data Processing Inequality(DPI) which states that given random variables X,Y and Z that form a Markov chain in the order X→Y→Z, then the mutual information between X and Y is greater than or equal to the mutual information between X and Z. Using this we have:

$$I(Y;X) \geq I(Y;Q(X))$$

By expanding the mutual information in terms of entropy we have:

$$H(Y) - H(Y|X) \geq H(Y)-H(Y|Q(X))$$

This leads us to our desired result:
$$H(Y|Q(X)) \geq H(Y|X)$$